# Blueimp jquery-file-upload, showing wrong file size for jpeg/jpg greater than 2MB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

While working with blueimg fileuploader library:
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

If I add jpeg/jpg image with more than 2MB it shows wrong file size. And uploaded file also has the wrong file size.

Is it a bug of the library or i'm missing any configuration?

I have found that filesize is changed after rendering with its template rendering script (https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates).

Edit:

Found the solution image resize option need to be disabled.

disableImageResize :true

Though default configuration is true.

Comment: Is the "uploaded file size" the same as "wrong file size"? Then it may acctually change the image?

Comment: Yes. It changes the image. According to their wiki ,default value of "disableImageResize" is true. But i needed to set its value again to true.

Answer (score 0):

I add an answer just so that other people will not come here trying to solve this since it's already resolved i take it.

OP needed to set the property `disableImageResize` to `true` to prevent the plugin from changing the images.